# I have shifted my wordpress site from one host to another, after shift the website wp-admin is not open

Tags: php, wordpress

I have shifted my wordpress site from one host to another, after shift the website wp-admin is not open and showing page cannot be displayed.http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/

Comment: Please read this -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/wp-login.php is there. try login

Answer (score 1):

Try To this URL [www.surmonteinfogen.com/wp-login.php](http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/wp-login.php)
It's Working and login to admin and Update Permalink Settings

Comment: thks for giving the response. but when I try to login it will redirect to https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php.

Comment: To check your database related to this URL [www.surmonteinfogen.com](http://www.surmonteinfogen.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can update your URI with `wp-login.php`.

First of all search for this line of code

```
require( dirname(__FILE__) . ‘/wp-load.php’ );
```

After this line add this code.

```
update_option(‘siteurl’, ‘http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/’ );
update_option(‘home’, ‘http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/’ );
```

Update the modified file to server and point your browser to http://www.surmonteinfogen.com/wp-login.php

Now your URI are updated.

Remove the added code from `wp-login.php` and upload back to server. Now you can use the admin panel. :)